# how to inject configs to every controller zend framework 2

Tags: php, config, zend-framework2

How to inject some config as an property to every controller in zf2 ? I tried to do that by setting it from onBootstrap or init methods but no results...

```
 $config = $e->getApplication();
 $controller = $e->getTarget();
 $controller->configs = $config;
```

when I try to get value set as default for controller property configs it works very well but setting is not working at all.

Comment: What kind of configs you mean? Basically you could write yourself your own `MyAbstractController` that includes a function like `getConfig()` which `return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config')`. This would return the full configuration array loaded from all module.config.php's

Answer (score 0):

Along with Sam's fine suggestion, another option would be writing a Controller Plugin. Then every controller can access that plugin. Moreover, the plugins are lazy loaded by the ServiceManager, so if your controller doesn't use it, then you don't get hit the performance cost of loading it.

See: http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.controllers.html#controller-plugins
and http://lab.empirio.no/custom-controller-plugin-in-zf2.html